# Can I use docker image registry from google cloud build?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

With Google Cloud Build, I am creating a trigger to build using a Dockerfile, the end result of which is a docker image.

I'd like to tag and push this to the standard Docker image repository (docker.io), but i get the following error:

The push refers to repository [docker.io/xxx/yyy]
   Pushing xxx/yyy:master
   denied: requested access to the resource is denied

I assume that this is because within the context of the build workspace, there has been no login to the Docker registry.

Is there a way to do this, or do I have to use the Google Image Repository?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Google Cloud Build to push to a different repository with a cloudbuild.yaml in addition to the Dockerfile.  You can log in to Docker by passing your password as an encrypted secret env variable.  An example of using a secret env variable can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/use-encrypted-secrets-credentials#example_build_request_using_an_encrypted_variable